# The request is not supported after FolderPicker PickSingleFolderAsync()

Tags: c#, windows, runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to open the FolderPicker on a Runtime project for Windows Phone 8.1, but when I call

```
await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

I get this:

The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)

This is the full method:

```
public async void openfolder()
        {
            FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
            folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
            StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        }
```

The method get fired only one time.
Please help, thanks and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem:
on Windows Phone 8.1

```
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
folderPicker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```

I have to use PickFolderAndContinue() not PickSingleFolderAsync()

Now everything functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to description of function "PickSingleFolderAsync" in visual studio which says "[deprecated]Not implemented for windows phone 8.1".